# Generating schema files with torque 4

Tags: java, maven, apache-torque

Has torque 4 lost the ability to generate schema files from a live database?

In torque 3 you could use "maven torque:jdbc" to generate the schema from the database which was nice, but it looks like torque 4 have lost that ability.

So do I have to write my xml schema files by hand with torque 4, or is there a way to auto generate them from either sql or a live database like in torque 3?

**------------- Added as per comment -------**

It seems my pom.xml is wrong somehow. I get the following error, when I try to run mvn generate-test-sources

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Eddie torque generator 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.197s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 24 22:43:25 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/240M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:1.0.0: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:1.0.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

My current pom.xml is: (It may be insanely wrong and stupid, because I have newer used maven before, and my project don't use maven for anything. So I don't really understand how maven works.).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Eddie</groupId>
  <artifactId>eddie</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Eddie torque generator</name>
  <version>1.0.0</version>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Torque runtime -->
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>torque-runtime</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.apache.torque</groupId>
      <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>8.4-701.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging via log4j -->
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.torque</groupId>
        <artifactId>torque-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <executions>

        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <packaging>classpath</packaging>
              <configPackage>org.apache.torque.templates.om</configPackage>
              <sourceDir>src/schema</sourceDir>
              <options>
                <torque.om.package>dk.mt3.libris.server.auto</torque.om.package>
                <torque.database>postgresql</torque.database>
              </options>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <id>generate-sql</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <packaging>classpath</packaging>
              <configPackage>org.apache.torque.templates.sql</configPackage>
              <sourceDir>src/schema</sourceDir>
              <defaultOutputDir>target/generated-sql</defaultOutputDir>
              <defaultOutputDirUsage>none</defaultOutputDirUsage>
              <options>
                <torque.database>postgresql</torque.database>
              </options>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

<!-- Insert start -->
<execution>
<id>generate-schema-from-jdbc</id>
<phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
<goals>
  <goal>generate</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
  <packaging>classpath</packaging>
  <configPackage>org.apache.torque.templates.jdbc2schema</configPackage>
  <newFileTargetDir>target/generated-schema</newFileTargetDir>
  <newFileTargetDirUsage>none</newFileTargetDirUsage>
  <options>
  <driver></driver>
  <url></url>
      <username>tiller</username>

  <torque.jdbc2schema.driver>org.postgresql.Driver</torque.jdbc2schema.driver>
    <torque.jdbc2schema.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/librisepubcreator</torque.jdbc2schema.url>
    <torque.jdbc2schema.user>tiller</torque.jdbc2schema.user>
    <torque.jdbc2schema.password></torque.jdbc2schema.password>
  </options>
</configuration>
</execution>
<!-- Insert end -->
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.torque</groupId>
            <artifactId>torque-templates</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
          <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/librisepubcreator</url>
          <username>tiller</username>
<!--
          <password></password>
-->
          <onError>continue</onError>
          <autocommit>true</autocommit>
          <fileset>
            <basedir>${basedir}/target/generated-sql</basedir>
            <includes>
              <include>*.sql</include>
            </includes>
          </fileset>
        </configuration>
       </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <!-- setting java version to 1.5 --> 
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>

        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Torque Maven plugin](http://db.apache.org/torque/torque-4.0/documentation/modules/maven-plugin/reference/index.html) now only offers a "generate" goal.

See "Generation of XML schema from an existing database" in the [Running the Generator](http://db.apache.org/torque/torque-4.0/documentation/orm-reference/running-the-generator.html) section.

In short, use `torque.jdbc2schema` options. Example:

```
<execution>
  <id>generate-schema-from-jdbc</id>
  <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>generate</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <packaging>classpath</packaging>
    <configPackage>org.apache.torque.templates.jdbc2schema</configPackage>
    <newFileTargetDir>target/generated-schema</newFileTargetDir>
    <newFileTargetDirUsage>none</newFileTargetDirUsage>
    <options>
      <torque.jdbc2schema.driver>${torque.driver}</torque.jdbc2schema.driver>
      <torque.jdbc2schema.url>${torque.database.url}</torque.jdbc2schema.url>
      <torque.jdbc2schema.user>${torque.database.user}</torque.jdbc2schema.user>
      <torque.jdbc2schema.password>${torque.database.password}</torque.jdbc2schema.password>
      <torque.jdbc2schema.schema>${torque.database.schema}</torque.jdbc2schema.schema>
    </options>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I want, but I can't get it to work. See -- added -- part to my question.

Comment: @MTilsted That error means that the version `1.0.0` of the `maven-compiler-plugin` is not available in the [Maven repository](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) that you are using. Use a more recent version, ie change `<version>1.0.0</version>` in your pom file to a more recent one. Maven repository can be browsed in order to see available versions: http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-77609479

Comment: That is fixed, but what should I set torque.jdbc2schema.driver to? I tried to use <torque.jdbc2schema.driver>org.postgresql.Driver</torque.jdbc2schema.driver> but that gives me "org.apache.torque.generator.source.SourceException: Could not find database driver class org.postgresql.Driver" so I guess I need to specify the jar file somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the Driver dependency:

```
...
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.torque</groupId>
        <artifactId>torque-templates</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
      </dependency>
       <dependency>
                <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>8.4-701.jdbc4</version>
         </dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin>
```

in your torque-4 plugin. The mechanism is, that the plugin reads all needed configuration from the torque-templates dependency. In this case from the classpath org.apache.torque.templates.jdbc2schema, where the conf and outlets configuration is found.